# How do I fill a tableview with placemarks?

Tags: swift, uitableview, clplacemark, mkplacemark

I want the user to select a specific sub-Administrative area. To do so, my plan is to show a table view with all Administrative areas (as sections) and sub-Administrative areas (as rows).
Any Idea on how I can do this?[image]